# Multiple Expand/Collapse Bootstrap buttons in a PHP foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My code is almost working, with one issue that I'm having a hard time fixing.  Here is some code that I have simplified.

```
    <?php for($counter = 0; $counter < 5; $counter++)
    {
    ?>
    <button type="button" id="<?php echo 'change_button_label_' . $counter?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="<?php echo '#button_number_' . $counter?>" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>Expand</button>

    <div id="<?php echo 'button_number_' . $counter?>" class="collapse">
        This gets collapsed #<?php echo "$counter"; ?>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('<?php echo "#change_button_label_" . $counter?>').click(function () {
            if($('button span').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'))
            {
                $('<?php echo "#change_button_label_" . $counter?>').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>Expand');
            }
            else
            {
                $('<?php echo "#change_button_label_" . $counter?>').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>Collapse');
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

If I try to click 1 or more buttons, they work in the sense that each will expand/collapse and reveal/hide its relevant content as expected.

However, only the 1st button that is clicked (and it doesn't matter which one is clicked 1st) will have its text and glyphicon changed from "expand" to "collapse."  All of the other buttons will continue to say "expand" regardless of if they are actually expanded or collapsed.

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out how to fix it so that the other buttons will toggle their text correctly when they are clicked.  I don't mind gutting my attempted code above if needed.

Actual output:

[image: Actual output when all buttons are expanded]

Expected output:

The text on each button should look like the first one after they've been clicked.  The expand/collapse feature is already working for each button.

Generated HTML/CSS output:
https://gist.github.com/bryanjamesmiller/c14e623152ab9b5f9246
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the generated HTML and JS?

Comment: I'm sorry I'll add a little more code

Comment: Added a GIST for the generated HTML and JS when the buttons have all expanded

Comment: ok, i updated my answer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your script block out of the PHP for loop and bind to the button element itself, rather than the button ID:

```
<?php for($counter = 0; $counter < 5; $counter++)
{
?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="<?php echo 'change_button_label_' . $counter ?>">DISLIKES<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
<?php 
}
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('button').click(function() {
        var $button = $(this),
            test = $button.text() === 'DISLIKES';

        if(test)
        {
            $button.text('LIKE');
            test=false;
        }
        else
        {
            $button.text('DISLIKES');
            test=true;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is pretty basic and will just change the button text. To toggle the icon as well you'd just need to do something like:

```
$button.addClass('like-class');
```

or

```
$button.removeClass('dislike-class');
```

In the appropriate `if` block

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xr4xzcsf/) to see it in action

Comment: It appears to be working.  You are a genius :) thank you for helping me.  Mind if I ask why that "test" variable is working without a $ in front of it?  Thanks again so much!!!

Comment: you only need the '$' for PHP variables. JavaScript variables are created using the var keyword, and can start with (almost) any character you like.

Comment: Aha.  Also, what is that comma doing in this line of code?  var $button = $(this),
            test = $button.text() === 'DISLIKES';

Comment: @heymrcarter elegant and neat answer, I like this solution

Comment: Typically, in JavaScript, you end most lines with a semicolon just like most other languages. However, when you are declaring variables you can chain them together with 1 var keyword, separated by commas. The alternative would be var $button = 'blah'; and on the next line, var test = true; Basically, it's a convention thing. Many places consider it to be cleaner code by chaining variable declarations

Comment: Last question :) (probably) how can I just select some of the buttons (I don't want my "submit" button for example having its text change)?  I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: just use a css class for the buttons you want to select. Let's just use 'toggle' as an example. Instead of $('button'), which selects all the <button>'s just do $('.toggle'), which will select all the elements with the class toggle. If you want to be sure you're only selecting  buttons with the class toggle you can just do $('button.toggle')

Comment: I ended up doing this:    https://gist.github.com/bryanjamesmiller/a30ff89144b8446774a0

Comment: That will certainly work, but you'll open a can of worms later when maintaining this thing. What happens when you need test3? what about test4...5...5, and so on. By just selecting the elements you really need you'll have a cleaner codebase and will get better performance on the DOM query.

Comment: Good point.  I'm noticing if I "double click" quickly, the button's label will get swapped so that expand and collapse work in reverse?  Any suggestions on that issue?

Comment: That can sometimes happen when binding click event handlers. Unfortunately there isn't a great way to deal with it. The most common solution is to unbind the click handler right after the click happens, do whatever, then rebind it. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/fb5w97m4/1/

Comment: Aha I did forget to add one line $button.off('click'); which was preventing it from working right!  Do you happen to know how I could apply this same "settimeout" feature to Bootstrap's collapse function?

Comment: @heymrcarter I was trying to combine your advice above with another StackOverflow question I'd been looking at.  Can you tell me if it's possible to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/nxh7e3zb/3/ that would avoid needing to use the settimeout()?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

change

```html
if($('button span').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'))
```

to

```html
if($('button#<?php echo 'change_button_label_' . $counter?> span').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'))
```

you are done !